# Chaining an operator that doesn't return an object

Tags: c++

I'm required to define a node class and that class needs to have **an overloaded '+' operator function which returns the sum of two nodes.**

I'm pretty comfortable doing this but I can't help but wonder why it should return the sum which would be say a double and thus, chaining for this operator would no longer be possible.

I mean, `node1 + node2` works but, `node1 + node2 + node3` won't.

**How do I achieve this combined sum of 5 nodes making use of the overloaded '+' operator which returns a double?**

Edit:

```
double Node::operator +(const Node& n) { return (this->weight + n.weight); }
```

Comment: What is the return type of your operator+()?, share your code

Comment: So you are trying to use node1+(double), that is not expected by your implementation.

Comment: Your assignment is wrong and you'll just have to turn in wrong code to complete the wrong assignment. You could also turn in correct code and lose points on your grade.

Answer (score 3):

There are two options. Either it makes sense for you to have "double + node", and you understand what that means, or you cannot return a double from the operator.

I'll elaborate. There is no tretinary operator + in C++ (nor any other language I'm aware of). Your node1 + node2 + node3 is really (node1 + node2) + node3. Let's number the operators, for easier reference, p1 and p2 (left is p1, right is p2).

Now you must decide which makes more sense. In particular, when looking at the semantics of what a "node" means, does it make sense to do "2.3 + node"? If so, simply define an operator+ that accepts one node and one double, and be done with it.

Taking this even further, if a node has little value beyond its value, you can create a node constructor that accepts a double, thus creating an implicit cast from double to node.

The alternative is to say that "double + node" makes no sense. Maybe a node has many aspects, its value being only one of them. If that's the case, and there is some meaningful way you can "add" two nodes, then you need your operator+ to return a node. No way around it.

Then there is the third option. If there is no way to add two nodes and get a third one, but there is also no sense in having "double + node", then you need a proxy class.

```
class node {
private:
  class node_value {
  public:
    double value;
    operator double() { return value; }
  }

  node_value operator+( const node &rhs );
  node_value operator+( const node_value &rhs );
};
```

operator+ for node returns a proxy class, which is implicitly convertible to double. It defines the first form of operator+ for the main addition, and the second form for the chained addition. You'd also need the swapped arguments operator defined outside the class, of course.

Comment: The proxy option is - IMHO - most elegant, but your current code will add the two leftmost `node`s yielding a `node_value` that can't be added to the next `node`. You'd could fix this with `node_value::operator+(const node& rhs)`.  You do have `node_value operator+( const node_value &rhs );` but it would need the `node_value`s on the right - while [`+` uses left-to-right evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)....

Comment: I mentioned that in the post code comment. For the sake of readability, I left out some of the implementation sweatwork.

Comment: ahhh... the "swapped arguments operator"... that'll do it too.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you also implement a cast operator, e.g. `operator double()`, you'll be able to implicitly cast the result of chained additions, and the following should work:

```
Node a(3.0);
Node b(7.0);
Node c(24.0);
double x = a + b + c;
```

Comment: Yes, this option sounds interesting. How do I implement the cast operator?

Comment: @MattMilna `Node::operator double() { return this->weight; }`, or more generally, `Node::operator TYPE()`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to add a node and a double, you can support multiple additions by defining addition of Nodes and doubles:

```
class Node {
  public:
    friend double operator+(double a, Node &b);
    double operator+(double b) {
      // however you get the sum here
      // for example, if the sum is a field of the node:
      return this->weight + b;
    }
}
double operator+(double a, Node &b) { return b + a; }
```

Note that we have to define both `Node + double` and `double + Node`, in order to support things like `a + (b + c)` in addition to `(a + b) + c`.

Edit: in response to your edit, I updated the code.

Comment: Pretty sure you intended that last line of this sample to be a free-function; not a member, especially since it would be illegal as the latter.

Comment: You're absolutely right WhozCraig, it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

For chaining, you can override `operator double` for `Node` like

```
struct Node {
   double operator+(const Node & n) const {
       return n.val + val;
   }

   Node(double val) : val(val) {}

   operator double() {
      return val;
   }

   double val;
};
```

Then you can do :

```
Node n1(1);
Node n2(2);
Node n3(3);
std::cout << n1 + n2 + n3 << endl; // 6
```

But this can cause confusion for the reader. Why ?? When you add two `ints` you expect a `int`. When you add two `Nodes` what do you expect ? A `double` or a `Node` ?

Therefore, if i have to do it:

```
struct NodeBetter {
  // Notice the return Type NodeBetter 
  NodeBetter operator+(const NodeBetter & n) const {
       return NodeBetter(n.val + val);
   }
   double val;
   NodeBetter(double val) : val(val) {}
};

 // in main()
 NodeBetter n1(1);
 NodeBetter n2(2);
 NodeBetter n3(3);
 std::cout << (n1 + n2 + n3).val << endl; // again 6. :)
```

See in Action : [Code](https://ideone.com/OLK40N)